# AWS Lambda - How to get libfontconfig available in my function

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, aws-lambda

My function code requires libfontconfig to work properly. It's a node function that generates a pdf from html. The pdf generates and everything, there is just random spaces in words here and there.

I have tried pretty much everything, I even built phantom.js myself on the same AmazonLinux AMI Lambda runs on. I just can't get it to work.

Is there any way I can simply package libfontconfig with my function code and then tell Lambda to put it where it needs to be? Or point phantom.js to my included libfontconfig somehow?

I've spent more than 2 days trying to get this thing working, can someone please get me out of this rabbit hole?

**EDIT**

I don't know too much about Linux, so please include detailed steps about where I can find things, etc.

Comment: could you provide some steps to reproduce the error?